# node.js exec command quote

Tags: node.js, exec

i have this command on linux to get my ip adress :

`connmanctl services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e '/IPv4 =/s/.*Address=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p'`

i want to use it in a exec function using Child Process like this :

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(' connmanctl services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e '/IPv4 =/s/.*Address=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' ', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

I got nothing and i dont know how i can exec a command with quote.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest options is to wrap the command in double quotes, but this may cause ESlint error, because of mixing double and single quotes.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(" connmanctl services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e '/IPv4 =/s/.*Address=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' ", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Another option is to use Template literals:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
 const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec(` connmanctl services ethernet_00142d000000_cable | sed -n -e '/IPv4 =/s/.*Address=\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' `, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
```